# Spring REST web service is slow on first request of each day

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, java-ws

I'am using spring rest web service.Its working fine.But it is slow on first request of each day.After that, all the calls are working great.Problem is only with the first call of the day.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You give no context whatsoever, there is a vast amount of possible reasons why this could be. What have you tried yet? Have you done some profiling? Do you know how/when potential caches are set up?

Comment: If by "first call of the day" you mean "first call to the container" then it's probably because a lot of things in your stack are "lazy instantiated" usually this is what you want. If this is not what you want, you can eager instantiate them in your ContextListener. If you literally mean first call of the day, then I suspect the cause to be infrastructure related.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke: Thanks.I mean firt call to the container.how to avoid lazy instantiation?

Comment: @Salman Look for performance hotspot in static intializers, especially singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your architecture and deployment, about a million things could contribute to this :-)
I am going to assume the web application is not shut down overnight, because that would be too obvious :-)

Still, all kinds of pools (thread pools, db connection pools, etc) might have spun down to near empty due to inactivity. The OS might have swapped out the pages of your JVM. DNS caches must have expired, so actual DNS lookups are needed again between every component in the system you identify with a domain name instead of a hardcoded IP. Same for ARP caches on endpoints and interim L2 switches.

So the simplest thing you can do is "keep the engine running", issue a periodic GET request from cron or quartz. Or just a "warmup" one every morning right before the start of business day.